# JQuery Date() Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone know why this doesn't work?

```
var lastReceivedBeginDate = new Date($("input[name='lastReceivedFromYear']").val(),$("input[name='lastReceivedFromMonth']").val(),$("input[name='lastReceivedFromDay']").val(),$("input[name='lastReceivedFromHour']").val(),$("input[name='lastReceivedFromMinute']").val(),$("input[name='lastReceivedFromSecond']").val());
```

Thx

Comment: *sigh* I can't believe it's come to this. `Date()`, a jQuery function!

Comment: `console.log(lastReceivedBeginDate);`

Comment: Which values are returned from the inputs? Probably they don't form a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you are missing the milliseconds parameter in the `Date` constructor.  From [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp), the constructor you are trying to use is

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

If that's not it, what error are you getting?  Are the values returned from `.val()` what you expect?

Comment: hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds are optional arguments in the `Date` constructor.

Comment: @Andy, you're absolutely right, thanks for pointing that out.  I'd say we'd need more info to help then...